# Can't find out what's wrong with this MySQL event syntax

Tags: mysql, node.js, events, syntax, sails.js

I'm trying to create a MySQL event, and this is the syntax I'm using:

```
CREATE EVENT test
    ON SCHEDULE AT FROM_UNIXTIME(1428005286)
    DO
      BEGIN
        UPDATE blog_posts SET status = 'published' WHERE id = 5;
      END
```

When I run it on **Node.js** (with the mySQL adapter, under Sails.js), I get no error, but the event doesn't get created. When I run it directly through phpMyAdmin, I get:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

I have also tried adding a semicolon to END, making it `END;`, and removing all semicolons, and it returns a slightly similar error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried removing the begin and end and just having the update??  I do not think you need begin and end with one liner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to start with:  create DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` ...
Also, since this is a one-liner, you don't need BEGIN..END

Comment: Removing the BEGIN ... END block does the trick. It wouldn't give back a syntax error if it was more than one statement? Also, what is the purpose of create DEFINER in this? Thanks.

Comment: You would have required DEFINER if privileges weren't kosher.   The Begin/End is for multiple statements, yes.